# Input type file (multiple) not working in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I got a form with an input

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" multiple>
</form>
```

When I upload files in that input, I'm trying to get those files with:

```
request.FILES
```

But I'm getting null object.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Show your view function and template code.

Comment: I don't have any logic in views.py, I'm just trying to get uploaded files with request.FILES.

Comment: What do you get if you print `request.method`, `request.content_type`, `request.POST` and `request.FILES` in your view when the form is submitted?

Comment: You haven't given the input a name?

Comment: @IainShelvington That's why it wasn't working. I totally forgot about it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hello @maca first of all you've to give name to your input field eg. ***``name="file"``*** and second one you're trying to access multiple files than you should use ``getlist()`` method eg. ***``request.FILES.getlist('file')``***